# Spring - Is there a way to display the id of a record after being registered with Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, thymeleaf

In my project I want to show the id of the record in the view with Thymeleaf after it has been inserted successfully.

Is there any way to get that result?

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_user")
    private Long idUser;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String lastName;

    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser= idUser;
    }
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName= firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName= lastName;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public void registerUser(User user) {
   userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Controller (To show the user's id after being registered):

```
public String userRegister(User user) {

    userService.registerUser(user);
    return "redirect:/home?success";
        
}
```

Thymeleaf (The idea to be able to display the id of the new user):

```
<span th:text="${idUser}"></span>
```

Comment: The method `save` from anything `Repository` returns the persisted entity. In other words, your method `registerUser` can return User.

Comment: Is there a method to return the new registered user id and display it with my code? Or is there something I'm doing wrong and it's not the correct way?

Comment: As I said, the `save` method of your `UserRepository` returns the `User` you just saved. I don't work with Thymeleaf so I'm not sure how to "send" or "update" the view with the new data (Though I think it's something with the `Model`), but with the `User` returned from the repository, you just need to call `getIdUser()` to get the Id..

Comment: Or just : `"redirect:/home?success&idUser"+user.getId()`!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning `String` you need to return `ModelAndView` so you can any property of User object

Controller

```
public ModelAndView userRegister(User user) {
    ModelAndView  model = new ModelAndView("home");
    User registerUser = userService.registerUser(user);
    model.addObject("registerUser",registerUser);
    return model;   
}
```

Repository

```
public User registerUser(User user) {
   return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Thymeleaf code

```
<span th:text="${registerUser.idUser}"></span>
```